# ansible on k8s get node where pod run

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

need get node name where pod run via ansible but without kubectl or command/shell usage

`ansible my_k8s -m k8s_info -a "kind=pod namespace=default name=testpod"`

it give me ansible_facts about this pod without node information

Thank you

k8s module also has nothing about node

Answer (score 0):

As you say, Ansible K8s modules don't provide node information.

However, you can get around this by running your Ansible Playbook to all K8s nodes (maybe by creating a dedicated host file) by running the command:

```
hostname && ls -l /var/log/pods | awk '{print $9}' | grep -i NAMESPACE | grep -i POD_NAME
```

Saving the output will give you the hostname/pod association you were looking for.
To do this, you can follow the steps described in the following link:
[Ansible: Store command's stdout in new variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059804/ansible-store-commands-stdout-in-new-variable)